# Urgent my favourite avocado tree is dying, please help me!

Tags: fruit-trees, watering, dryness

[[image: this is the top partthis is the rest of the stem]

I planted  my avocado tree almost a year ago and I forgot to water it for 2 weeks due to my exams. It looks dried up now. The top of the stem looks wrinkled and shrivelled, but the rest of the stem is green and hard. This is my favourite tree and I am heart broken. What can I do to save it? I have watered it a week ago, and since the soil is still wet I aerated the soil a lil. The stem even had white fungus like stuff on it, which I wiped away and nothing of that sort has come back. But I don't know what to do or how to save my tree
UPDATE- THE TOP HALF OF THE STEM HAS GONE HOLLOW AND THIS IS REALLY HEARTBREAKING, this tree has been with me through thick and thin and i dont want to lose him yet

Answer (score 2):

It's quite normal for avocado to have hollow stems in green immature branches and shoots, so nothing to worry about there. Drying is more of an issue; keep moist for a while and hope that the main stem sends out new shoots or a new main stem emerges at ground level. Once new growth appears cut out the dead parts.